# The type cannot be used as type 'T' in the generic type or method. There is no implicit reference conversion from to

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I'm trying to write a generic method to check if List is null or empty and throw an exception.

This is what I have:

```
public static void IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T argument) where T : List<T>
{
   if (argument == null || argument.Count == 0)
   {
        throw new ArgumentException("Argument " + nameof(argument) + " can't be null or empty list.");
   }
}
```

The problem is with calling this method; I trying to call this method like this:

```
ThrowIf.Argument.IsNullOrEmpty<List<ParameterServiceReference.Parameter>>(options.Parameters);
```

Where options.Parameters is type of: `List<ParameterServiceReference.Parameter>.`

I'm getting this error:

```
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ParameterServiceReference.Parameter>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<ParameterServiceReference.Parameter>>
```

If I call method like this:

```
ThrowIf.Argument.IsNullOrEmpty<ParameterServiceReference.Parameter>(options.Parameters);
```

I get this error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Layer.ParameterServiceReference.Parameter>' to 'Project.Layer.ParameterServiceReference.Parameter'
```

Is this kind of generic method possible with generic collection or not, in the solution I will have many generic lists of different classes and I think it's not smart to write so many overloaded methods.

Comment: Well, of course `T` can't be a `List<T>`. How could it? C# doesn't support recursive types :D You need to add another a separate type argument for the list and for the elements of the list.

Comment: In addition to what @Luaan said, you don't need to specify the type when you are calling it. Also you misspelled throw if that matters at all.

Try `ThrowIf.Argument.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Parameters);` after you fix the recursive type

Comment: Or just take in `ICollection<T>` or even just `List<T>` itself and don't bother with generic type parameter constraints...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generic constraint specifically says that the parameter needs to be some type that is a List where the generic type of the list is *itself*.  When you say `where T : List<T>` you're saying that the generic argument, `T`, needs to be a `List<T>` where `T` is the type you're adding the constraint for.

What you should *really* do here is just have the method accept a `List<T>`, not a `T` where `T` is a `List`:

```
public static void IsNullOrEmpty<T>(List<T> argument) { //...
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `List<T>` in the parameter's type?

Comment: @Servy Thx :). this do the trick, sometimes is better to not bother with constraints where is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a constraint that's `T : List<T>`, just like you can't have a type `MyList` that inherits from `MyList` (or type `T` that inherits from `List<T>`).

Just use `public static void IsNullOrEmpty<T>(List<T> argument)`

Comment: You *can* actually have a constraint like that.  The method will even compile just fine.  There's just no valid type that will ever be able to fulfill that constraint.

Comment: @Servy There actually is - that's how enums work in Java, basically. But it only really makes sense for interfaces, and even then it's quite limited.

Comment: For interfaces it's actually a rather *common* pattern.  You actually see it with a rather high percentage of generic interfaces.  It's with a class that it's not possible to create an object that is its own generic argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
public static void IsNullOrEmpty<S,T>(T argument) where T : List<S>
{
    if (argument == null || argument.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Argument " + nameof(argument) + " can't be null or empty list.");
    }
}
```

Now you can call your method:

```
ThrowIf.Argument.IsNullOrEmpty<ParameterServiceReference.Parameter, List<ParameterServiceReference.Parameter>>(options.Parameters);
```